# UISearchBar url request

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a downloader in which I am trying to get the pasted text in my search bar to start downloading on tapping the return key.

How would I get the search bar to send a request to the pasted text to initialize the download?

What I'm calling:

```
NSString *pasteboardString = searchBar.text;
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pasteboardString];
```

What needs to get triggered:

```
[self downloadURL:*HAS TO BE URL* userInfo:nil];
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to figure out here. Are you trying to figure out how to capture the text from the pasteboard? Are you trying to determine how to make a networking request from a URL?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a networking request from a URL. The URL is my search bar text pasted from the pasteboard.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you're asking. Is the text coming from the pasteboard? Based on the provided code, it looks as if it's coming from the search bar. Is your question how to make sure that the provided URL is valid?

Comment: I have a search bar. Text gets inputed via the pasteboard. Goal is to get that inputed string and download the contents. The download starts in the downloadURL portion.

Comment: Do you have the `UISearchBarDelegate` set up?

Comment: Yes I have the UISearchBarDelegate declared in my .h file in the interface bracket.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring it out. In case somebody finds this useful.

```
#pragma mark - Firing Download
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        // Do the search...
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchBar.text];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        bool valid = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req];

        if(valid)
        {
            [self downloadURL:url userInfo:nil];
            NSLog(@"Valid URL - %@",searchBar.text);
            [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
            [searchBar setText:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [alert showError:@"Enter valid url"];
            [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            [searchBar setText:nil];
        }
    });
    NSLog(@"Search Button Pressed");
}
```